# I can't get the average of all the nodes to print in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm messing around with nodes in Java so I can get better accustomed to them.
I made a simple Node Class.
Then in my main class, I tried to get the average of all the nodes.
When I try to print it there is no error and I have multiple methods to be able to test the outputs but when I run it everything prints fine except for the average.
I'm using Eclipse as an IDE and no error is showed but when I run the code it compiles and runs without an issue but I still can't get it to print the average.

```
public class Node {
    double a;
    Node next;

    Node() {
    
    }

    Node(double i){
        this.a = i;
    }


}

public class LLPractice {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Node n1 = new Node(60.1);
        Node n2 = new Node(30.2);
        Node n3 = new Node(40.4);
        Node n4 = new Node(50.5);
    
        n1.next = n2;
        n2.next = n3;
        n3.next = n4;
    
        System.out.println();
        traverse(n1);
    
        System.out.println();
        double d = sumup(n1);
        System.out.println("Summation: " + d);
    
        // Find the min and max and average numbers in the linked list
        double x = getMin(n1);
        System.out.println("Minimum: " + x);
    
        double y = getMax(n1);
        System.out.println("Max: " + y);
    
        double z = getAvg(n1);
        System.out.println("Average: " + z);
    
    }

    static double getAvg(Node head){
        double total = 0;
        int numOfNodes = 0;
        Node temp = head;
        while(temp != null) {
            temp.a += total;
            numOfNodes++;
        }
        double avg = total/numOfNodes;
        return avg;
    }

    static double getMax(Node head) {
        double max = head.a;
        Node temp = head;
        while(temp != null) {
            if(max < temp.a) {
                max = temp.a;
            }
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        return max;
    }

    static double getMin(Node head) {
        double min = head.a;
        Node temp = head;
        while(temp != null) {
            if(min > temp.a) {
                min = temp.a;
            }
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        return min;
    }

    static double sumup(Node head) {
        double sum = 0;
        Node temp = head;
        while(temp != null) {
            sum += temp.a;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    static void traverse(Node head){
        Node temp = head;
    
        while(temp != null) {
            System.out.println(temp.a);
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `temp.a += total;` Backwards: `total += temp.a;`

Comment: You also forgot `temp = temp.next;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total doesn't change.  Your summing in temp.a

```
   static double getAvg(Node head){
        double total = 0;
        int numOfNodes = 0;
        Node temp = head;
        while(temp != null) {
            temp.a += total; // <-- problem is here. reverse these and make
                             // sure you iterate thru the nodes.
            numOfNodes++;
        }
        double avg = total/numOfNodes; 
        return avg;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, apologize I had it written correctly in the actual project but I copied it wrong. It still doesn't print the average for some reason. The word "Average" doesn't even print after I call the method "getAvg."

Comment: As I said in my comments in the answer you're not iterating thru temp.  So you need to do `temp = temp.next.`  Otherwise, the method never returns  because null is never seen.